# Outputting only p-value for ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova, p-value

I'm doing some basic one-way ANOVA in R. It would be useful to be able to output only the p-value associated with a *specific* term without producing the whole ANOVA table (unrelated reason). I need the value as a basic numeric and not an ANOVA object For example, if I'm looking at `anova(lm(yield~variety+block))` and just want the p-value for "variety", is there a straightforward way? Thanks!

Comment: `anova(lm(yield~variety+block))$"Pr(>F)"[1]` or any number of other ways of accessing a particular element of a vector that's a particular element of a list. See `str(anova(lm(yield~variety+block)))`

Comment: @Glen_b, why not make that an 'official' answer? Also, this question is *only* about how to get something done in R & not about any related statistical topics, so it will need to be migrated to SO or closed.

Comment: @gung done. I wanted to make sure the OP got some kind of answer before it got closed. It happened more slowly than I expected.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize this was off topic. Fwiw, I have 17 response variables (yield is one of them) and I wanted to loop through 17 ANOVAs with each response variable to see which one had the most significant p-value. If this background info doesn't make my question more appropriate for this forum, that's fine. Sorry for the misinterpretation.

Answer (score 6):

`anova` like almost all other functions in R, creates an object. Many data analysis functions create a named list of pieces of information, some of which is displayed and possibly other parts for use by other functions.

See `str(anova(lm(yield~variety+block)))` to get a sense of what's there.

As it stands, `anova` outputs a named list. The list element with the p-values can be accessed by name, `anova(lm(yield~variety+block))$"Pr(>F)"`, or by element number, `anova(lm(yield~variety+block))[[5]]`. Either gives you a vector with all the p-values.

You appear to want the first one of those, element `[1]`. So

`anova(lm(yield~variety+block))$"Pr(>F)"[1]`, or

`anova(lm(yield~variety+block))[[5]][1]` should do it.

Note that `str` says it's a data frame (which is a special kind of list you can treat a bit like a matrix), so you can also do this: `anova(lm(yield~variety+block))[1,5]`, which is probably the easiest of all.

(There are a number of other ways of accessing a particular element of a vector that's a particular element of a list, which should also work.)

If you want to play with the whole anova table, you should assign it to a variable:

```
aa <- anova(lm(yield~variety+block))
```

and then you can pull out whatever you want:

```
aa[1,5]
```

You can then rename or replace parts of it, to make it look however you need - but if you change it in substantial ways, you may want to remove the `'anova'` class in case it no longer meets the requirements to be an anova table.